# MacBook keeps connecting to guest network (Airport)

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, airport

Every time I open my MacBook Pro (restart or from sleep) it is always connected to my Guest Network. I have to manually connect to my regular network in order to access my other apple devices and use airplay. I connect via an Airport time capsule.

Answer (score 5):

Select System Preferences / Network / Advanced and drag your regular network to the head of the list. You may also remove the guest network from that list by selecting it and pressing the `-` button.